# SQL Server database table column size limitation issue when creating the table from LabVIEW 2018

Tags: labview

I'm trying to the write the values to SQL Server Express database from LabVIEW 2018. I am using String as a datatype for my table columns. Since I am using String datatype, I have to provide a size of the column. My data contain nearly than 10000 characters. So, I given size of the column as 10000. But when I am trying the run this code I am getting the error. Refer to the screenshot below.

My question is, is there any column size limitation for the string datatype in LabVIEW? If yes, how can I give more than 8k characters into one column.

Attached here Front Panel and Block Diagram of my code.

[image: Front Panel]

[image: Block Diagram]

Regards,

Azad

Comment: SQL Server has `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` datatypes - the first is the **non-Unicode** version, and it has an upper limit of **8000 characters** for a single column; the second is the **Unicode** version, which has a limit of **4000** characters. If you need more (really?!?!?), then you need to use `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column types which support up to 2 GB (2 **billion** characters) of non-Unicode (and 1 GB / 1 billion chars. of Unicode) text

Comment: It **always helps** to consult the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on such topic - that **should be** your first stop for **any** question that pops up about SQL Server ......